# Replace HDD with SSD, / I.D. & auto-mount

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a System 76 NUC/Meercat i7, with a Samsung 950PRO 512GB PCIe NVMe boot drive, and a secondary 2TB HDD. (Ubuntu 16.04 is located on the boot drive)

I had instant remorse, and bought a 2TB 850EVO SSD to replace the existing 2TB HDD (both drives are empty). However, upon boot it did not recognize the 2TB SSD. I assume I need to I.D & auto-mount the drive. I'm not going to partition the drive, It's for bulk storage.

Also, will I need to take steps to insure AHCI has been activated for this drive (instead of IDE)?

Would appreciate any help you can offer, at beginner's level please!

Comment: Linux does not like unpartitioned drives. Many tools will not work. Some have copied lots of data then could not mount as mount expects partitions. It becomes a "SuperFloppy" and has to be mounted special. AHCI is a setting in UEFI/BIOS. Most just have one setting for all drives, but some can set by groups. Use gpt partitioning also. I like to include a small install on every drive, even if just emergency boot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu You also need to set ownership & permissions.

Comment: The super floppy concept might be the way the original HDD was installed.

Comment: It was listed on the file tree as "extra drive" does that mean that it only mounted when selected, like a big thumb drive?

Comment: Normally external drives are only mounted when selected, unless already manually mounted. Default auto mount is by UUID of partitions, but if you label partition then it mounts with the label like /media/$USER/label or UUID. $USER is your login id/name.